# Fade-in Animation Not Working in JavaScript Image Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problem: I'm working on an image slideshow on my website that should have a fade-in animation when switching between images by clicking on banner buttons. I've used JavaScript to achieve this, but the animation isn't working as expected.

Description: I've implemented an image carousel with three images and corresponding banner buttons. When I click on the banner buttons, the image should switch with a fade-in animation, but currently, the switch happens without any animation.

Code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  const banners = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-banner");
  const imageTitle = document.getElementById("image-title");
  const imageText = document.getElementById("image-text");
  const arrowIcon = document.getElementById("image-arrow");

  // Legg til tittel, tekst og lenke for hver slide
  const slideData = [{
      title: "Seil",
      text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      link: "https://www.seil.no"
    },
    {
      title: "Solseil",
      text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      link: "https://www.solseil.no"
    },
    {
      title: "Rigg",
      text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      link: "https://www.rigg.no"
    }
  ];

  // Funksjon for å oppdatere teksten og lenken basert på valgt slide
  function updateSlideInfo(slideIndex) {
    imageTitle.textContent = slideData[slideIndex].title;
    imageText.textContent = slideData[slideIndex].text;
    arrowIcon.setAttribute("data-link", slideData[slideIndex].link);
  }

  // Forhindrer standard klikkoppførsel på tab-bannere
  banners.forEach((banner, index) => {
    banner.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Forhindrer standard klikkoppførsel
      const tabId = banner.id.replace("-banner", "");
      banners.forEach((b, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          b.classList.add("active");
          b.classList.remove("inactive");
        } else {
          b.classList.add("inactive");
          b.classList.remove("active");
        }
      });
      // Oppdater teksten for valgt slide
      updateSlideInfo(index);
      // Skjul alle bilder
      slides.forEach((slide) => {
        slide.classList.remove("active");
      });
      // Vis valgt slide
      slides[index].classList.add("active");
    });
  });

  // Legg til klikkfunksjonalitet for pilen
  arrowIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const link = this.getAttribute("data-link");
    if (link) {
      // Håndter hva som skal skje når pilen klikkes
      // Her kan du legge til lenken eller handlingen du ønsker
      window.location.href = link;
    }
  });

  // Initial visning (for eksempel Seil som standard)
  banners[0].classList.add("active");
  updateSlideInfo(0);
  slides[0].classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out!important;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.gradient-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 1%, transparent 35%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.tab-banners {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  z-index: 99;
}

.tab-banner {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #A4A4A4;
  /* Farge for inaktive bannere */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans',
}

.tab-banner.active {
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: white;
  /* Farge for den aktive bannen */
}

.tab-banner.inactive {
  color: #A4A49B;
}


/* Stil for tekstseksjonen */

.text-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.text-section h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.text-section p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: white;
}

.arrow-icon {
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="" alt="Logo">
</div>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>

  <div class="slide" id="seil">
    <img src="" alt="Seilbilde">
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="solseil">
    <img src="" alt="Solseilbilde">
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="rigg">
    <img src="" alt="Riggbilde">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-banners">
  <div class="tab-banner active" id="seil-banner">
    Seil
  </div>
  <div class="tab-banner" id="solseil-banner">
    Solseil
  </div>
  <div class="tab-banner" id="rigg-banner">
    Rigg
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-section">
  <h1 id="image-title">Tittel for valgt bilde/tab</h1>
  <p id="image-text">Dette er teksten som tilhører valgt tab/container.</p>
  <div class="arrow-icon" id="image-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Expected Behavior: When I click on a banner button, I expect the selected image to display with a fade-in animation.

Current Behavior: When I click on a banner button, the image changes immediately without any animation.

What I've Tried: I've attempted to add a transition in CSS for the image elements and used JavaScript to modify the opacity of the images when switching them. I've also experimented with setTimeout, but I haven't been able to make the fade-in animation work as expected.

Comment: This is caused by `display: none`. I suggest you switch to using visibility instead: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.php